# How to improve the graph for an implicit function $|\sin x|^y + |\cos x|^y = 1$

Tags: graphics

I've recently posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869092/what-is-the-plot-of-this-implicit-function-sin-xy-cos-xy-1) on Math.SE related to the graph of the following function: 
$$
|\sin x|^y + |\cos x|^y = 1$$

I had some troubles with transforming the function to see what the graph looks like so decide to refer to desmos, W|A and Mathematica neither of which gave me the exact plot. I would like to know:

> Is it possible to improve the graph or apply some (general) technique so that it's more accurate than the ones by the link?

Here is a snippet for copy and paste: `ContourPlot[Abs[Cos[x]]^y + Abs[Sin[x]]^y == 1, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, 0, 3}]`

And its output:

[image: plot]

Please note that i'm fairly new to Mathematica and may miss something that may be obvious for an experienced user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refinement of a plot can be achieved with the Option  `MaxRecursion -> ...`

```
ContourPlot[Abs[Cos[x]]^y + Abs[Sin[x]]^y == 1, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer, you could not reproduce it due to my fault. I was plotting it for $x \in [- \pi , \pi]$. I've just updated the OP

Comment: If $x=\frac \pi 2$, then $ y$ may be an arbitrary positive real number. The same issue with $x=− \frac \pi 2$ and $x=\pi$ and $x=−\pi$.

Comment: The MaxRecursion -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 12 options make the realistic plot.